# How to compare floating numbers with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating

I would like to compare to floating numbers with JavaScript.

```
let a = 117.454;      // type: number
let b = 6.685;        // type: number
console.log(a < b);   // problem: return 'true'
```

Comment: ?? 117.454 is greater than 6.685 — what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Curious, why would `117.454` be less that `6.685`? did you mean to use `>` (greater than) instead?

Comment: like the others, I cannot understand the question. I am guessing you want to compare the typeof. If that is what you are looking for, you can do with like this: `console.log(typeof a === typeof b);`

Comment: I found my problem: I believed that a and b were numbers. Actually, there were strings. First, I had numbers with 12 decimals but I need only 3 decimals; .toFixed(3) changed the numbers to strings...

Comment: @Remiswl that still doesn't explain why you expect `a < b` to be true?

Comment: I would like to compare the two numbers: if(a < b) {...}

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely dealing with strings and you need to `parseFloat` the values. Maybe like so

```
const isGreater=> (a,b) => (parseFloat(a)-parseFloat(b)) > 0;
```

Comment: Without clarification from the OP I don't see how we can know that

Comment: I don't know that :)

Comment: OP has clarified that the numbers were in fact strings. 

Comment: I found my problem: I believed that a and b were numbers. Actually, there were strings. First, I had numbers with 12 decimals but I need only 3 decimals; .toFixed(3) changed the numbers to strings...